# pandas syntax examples confusion

Tags: pandas

I am confused by some of the examples I see for pandas.  For example this is shortened from a post I recently read:

`df[df.duplicated()|df()]`

What I don't understand is why `df` needs to be on the outside: `df[df.duplicated()]`
vs just using `df.duplicated()`.  In the documentation I have not yet seen the first example, everything is presented in the format `df.something_doing()`.  But I see many examples such as `df[df.something_doing()]` and I don't understand what the `df` on the outside does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

df.duplicated() returns the boolean values. They provide a mask with True if the condition mentioned is satisfied, False otherwise.
If you want a slice of the dataframe based on the boolean mask, you need:

```
df[df.duplicated()]
```

Another simple example, consider this dataframe

```
    col1  id
0   1     a
1   0     a
2   1     a
3   1     b
```

If you only want the columns where 'id' is 'a',

```
df.id == 'a'
```

would give you boolean mask but

```
df[df.id == 'a']
```

would return the dataframe

```
    col1   id
0   1      a
1   0      a
2   1      a
```